# Logstash File plugin custom delimiter

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I'm using logstash for quite a time. I tried using a custom delimiter in File plugin. I'm reading a static file. I see file plugin extracts 32KB data and passes it to tokenizer for splitting by delimiter.

```js
 data = watched_file.file_read(32768)
 changed = true
 watched_file.buffer_extract(data).each do |line|
   listener.accept(line)
 @sincedb[watched_file.inode] += (line.bytesize + @delimiter_byte_size)
 end
```

What happens when the last byte is not new line ( ie: part of a line ). My regex fails on the partial line and skips that. I lose an event in this case. I have seen this on a custom delimiter which can happen on \n delimiter as well.
Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/47) will help. Basically, there's a known issue with that modifier.